# Suspending every 10 seconds

Tags: 16.04, suspend

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my old netbook.

Now every 10 seconds the netbook keeps suspending. I changed the settings in brightness and lock and power so that it doesn't suspend, but it had no effect.

What can I do to stop this?

EDIT: I got it working... It worked when I changed when the lid is closed to do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

As you said its an old computer, this is probably a hardware issue with the reed switch from the lid.

Try disabling the auto suspend when lid is closed.

If it doesn't work, type in a terminal (this will prevent suspend as long as the bash session is still open, giving you time to debug the problem):

```
sudo systemd-inhibit /bin/bash
```

And then try to determine what is causing the suspend event using:

```
dbus-monitor --system
```

or

```
udevadm monitor
```

Comment: Please, remember to accept my answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes kernels dont really support sertian notebooks. I recommend upgrading to kernel 4.6

Here is kernel 4.6 (Make sure this in a seperate folder and not with any other .deb files.)

**64Bit:**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**32Bit**:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_i386.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```