# Windows tablet, installed ubuntu 17.10. Keeps suspending after few seconds. Tried everything

Tags: suspend, 17.10

Tablet details - GoClever Insignia 800 Win, Intel Atom Z3735E

First of all, I tried doing the "HandleLidSwitch=ignore". I tried putting almost everything to ignore in that file(logind.conf). Did not stop. When I try "sudo chmod 444 /sys/power/state" it only stops from fully suspending. Meaning, that the screen goes black, then again on, but it is locked. So I have to type the password again.

I tried this "sudo systemd-inhibit /bin/bash" as was stated in one of the answers of this question - [Suspending every 10 seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786537/suspending-every-10-seconds). But this did not help. It still kept suspending.

The screen seems to not fully go off, but stays black until I press the power button, then it goes back to lock screen.

I did not experience this problem in the installation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have to be ashamed of myself.

For some reason when changing the "HandleLidSwitch=ignore" option in "/etc/systemd/logind.conf" I did not notice that the options were ***COMMENTED OUT*** by default. So that was my mistake. So many hours wasted. I hope my answer will make people check twice, if they maybe forgot to do the same as I did.